# Using UE4 with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I recently did some cleaning of my drives. I decided to install visual studio 2017 after cleaning the drives up. I have been trying to continue work on my old UE4 project using the engine pulled from GitHub. I tried rebuilding the project with VS2017 which I know is not fully supported yet. I did run into quite a few problems, including the missing corecrt.h files. I reinstalled the Windows SDK to fix this.

The current problem is a new missing file called windows.h, and I believe it is missing due to the build tools looking for the wrong version of the SDK. I was wondering, has anyone else successfully integrated Visual Studio 2017 with their UE4 project after running into similar problems?

*-- Edited due to poor grammar.*

Comment: One other detail. The errors seem to be centered around the ShaderCompileWorker project within the solution. It won't allow me to build the editor from the source code collected from github. I ran setup.bat and generateprojectfiles.bat -2017, but it does not affect the issue. I will continue looking into this.

Comment: Here is a link to a person with a similar problem in which he was forced to use temporary fixes for these issues.https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/547647/packaging-with-visual-studio-2017-rc.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know Version 4.15 supports both Visual Studio 2015 (default) and Visual Studio 2017.  If you are building the Engine from source code, you would want to open a command prompt after running `Setup.bat` and run the command `GenerateProjectFiles.bat -2017`. This will give you a **Visual Studio 2017** solution for the Engine.

To use Visual Studio 2017 for projects, you can set your preference for which version projects use by going to *Edit -> Editor Preferences -> General -> Source Code*  and choosing *Visual Studio 2017* in the *Source Code Editor* setting.

Answer (score 1):

If regenerating the Engine's VS project files doesn't help. Try regenerating your own UE4 project's VS project files.

With Visual Studio and UE4 closed, find the .uproject file, right click and select `Generate Visual Studio project files`.

Open the solution, make sure your UE4 game (e.g. MyProject) under the Games folder is set as the StartUp project (right click, `Set as StartUp project`), then try a compile.